# how do I set custom status?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to get a custom status in to my ready.js but it doesnt seem to work

```
import fs from 'fs';

const once = true;
const name = 'ready';

async function invoke(client) {
    const commands = fs
        .readdirSync('./events/commands')
        .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'))
        .map((file) => file.slice(0, -3));

    const commandsArray = [];

    for (let command of commands) {
        const commandFile = await import(`#commands/${command}`);
        commandsArray.push(commandFile.create());
    }

    client.application.commands.set(commandsArray);
    console.log(`Successfully logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    
    client.user.setActivity('test', { type: 'STREAMING' });

}

export { once, name, invoke };
```

I tried putting the

```
    client.user.setActivity('test', { type: 'STREAMING' });
```

in diffrent areas but still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing `fs from ‘fs’` you can do:

```
const fs = require(“fs”)
```

To set the bot's activity you need to import `ActivityType` at the top of the document:

```
const { ActivityType } = require(“discord.js”)
```

And this is how you set the actual status:

```
client.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: 'activity', type: ActivityType.Playing }], status: 'idle' });
```

Comment: _"Instead of importing `fs` from `fs` you can do"_, but why would you do that? _"type in `npm i fs` in the terminal"_. Again, why would you do that? `fs` is not an npm package.

Comment: `fs` is and npm package. Just like `dotenv` @ZsoltMeszaros

Comment: It is not. Can you send me a link to the npm site where you can find the fs package then? :D

Comment: Here is the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs), I’ve recently tried out the `ms` package and I had to install it just like you do with `fs`. `npm i ms` or in this case `npm i  fs`.

Comment: Ah, there is a difference between `ms` and `fs` :) Have you read the text on the page you linked? _"This package name is not currently in use, but was formerly occupied by another package. To avoid malicious use, npm is hanging on to the package name, but loosely, and we'll probably give it to you if you want it."_

Comment: I know but it is still needed in this situation where we are using `fs`. So we can run `npm i fs` and npm _will probably give it to you if you want it._ It works for me.

Comment: Please, don't use `npm i fs`. I don't know why you think it's needed or why you're struggling to understand that it's a bad idea. Again, **don't use** `npm i fs`.

Comment: I don’t understand why to **not** use it when YouTubers install it in the terminal with `npm i fs`. Please give me some evidence that backs up your thought.

Comment: `fs` is a built-in Node.js file system module. It's not on npm. It comes with Node.js just like `assert`, `crypto`, `events`, `path`, `timers`, etc. Have you read the [page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs) you linked yourself? `fs` on npm is a *placeholder* package. It doesn't contain anything, just a `package.json` file and a `README`. I don't really care what some random YouTuber does. Have you heard of [Sturgeon's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law)? It's definitely true for YouTubers. Everyone makes mistakes. I've just tried to help you so you won't make the same mistake

Comment: Thanks you @ZsoltMeszaros for your help. I appreciate it! Thanks for correcting me. I made some further research and noticed that the `fs` package **is** included in the Node.js installation, just like you said. Let’s move on, the question is closed and seem to be answered in another question. Thanks for your help.